# 2d unity , How to drag an object using touch/finger on x axis only

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, touch

There's someone here can help me. Im new to unity. I was working on making objects moves only on x-axis / y-axis when the object touch and drag to the left the object moves to left and stops when the touch or removes on the object.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveScriptVertical : MonoBehaviour 
{
    //touch offset allows ball not to shake when it start moving

    float deltax,deltay;
    Rigidbody2D rb;

    bool moveAllowed = false;

    void Start ()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        //touch event
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch (0);

            //knowing the touch position
            Vector2 touchPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);

            //touch phase

            switch (touch.phase)
            {
            case TouchPhase.Began:
                //if you touch the car
                if (GetComponent<Collider2D> () == Physics2D.OverlapPoint (touchPos)) 
                {
                    //get the offset between position you touch
                    deltax = touchPos.x - transform.position.x;
                    deltay = touchPos.y - transform.position.y;

                    //if touch began within  the car collider
                    //then it is allowed to move

                    moveAllowed = true;

                    //restriction some rigidbody properties
                    rb.freezeRotation = true;
                    rb.velocity = new Vector2 (0, 0);
                    GetComponent<BoxCollider2D> ().sharedMaterial = null;
                }
                break;

            //you move your finger
            case TouchPhase.Moved:                   
                //if you touches the car and move is allowed
                if (GetComponent<Collider2D> () == Physics2D.OverlapPoint (touchPos) && moveAllowed)
                    rb.MovePosition (new Vector2 (0, touchPos.y - deltay));

                break;

            //you released your finger
            case TouchPhase.Ended:
                //restore intial parameters
                //when touch is ended
                moveAllowed = false;
                rb.freezeRotation = true;
                rb.gravityScale = 0;
                PhysicsMaterial2D mat = new PhysicsMaterial2D ();
                GetComponent<BoxCollider2D> ().sharedMaterial = mat;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what your problem is, can you please post some code or image or even describe better what is your problem?

Comment: Did you already try something? Do you have some code that moves on both axes and you want to restrict to x axis only, or are you asking how to detect a touch in Unity?

Comment: I dont have any code. rightnow.

Comment: Yes , i want some code that the object moves on x axis only and how to detect if the object has been touch so the object can be move

Comment: why not use the MouseDown method. And I think it can solve your issue quiet easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some libraries that allow you to have complex finger events, for instance [Touchscript](https://github.com/TouchScript/TouchScript/wiki). If you choose this solution you will find tutorials online.

The most basic way is to use unity's Input class with a nice doc here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html

This allow you to know when a finger touched the screen or moved on the screen. It will give you x an y coordinate so if you just want to move along x you would use only the x value, and, for example translate your object with it using

```
transform.Translate(new Vector3(x, 0f, 0f));
```

**Edit**

Since you use touchscript, have a look at TransformGesture, it should allow you to handle many transform events. If you want to have more control, you can use PressGesture, PanGesture and ReleaseGesture instead

Comment: Yes. Im using touchscript. Thanks i will chech this out

Comment: You can validate the answer or vote for it if it was useful, otherwise feel free to extend your question if something is still not clear

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/zNX1L) this is the link of the photo , right now. i have a code that that move the object that has been touch and move where the touches move , in the photo the RED COLOR TO KNOW THE THAT THE OBJECT HAS BEEN TOUCH , NEXT THE YELLOW ARROW DOWN REPRESENT WHERE THE FINGER MOVES. and the blue marker that the place where the car goes when the user move his finger.

Comment: is the blue marker the position that you want to achieve? or should the car follow the yellow line but wrongly goes to the blue marker?

Comment: the car should follow the yellow line but wrongly goes to the blue marker, im sorry for the contruction of my sentence, I have a fever right now

Comment: I think `rb.MovePosition (new Vector2 (0, touchPos.y - deltay));` is not doing what you want. It sets the position exactly, it is not a translation. so if you put x = 0, if will go in the center. In the begin case, store the x position. Then on each move, set the position to `Vector2(startX, yTouch)`.

Comment: Do you mean that i don't need to subtract the touchpos.y to deltay?  And want do you mean to the startx?

Comment: you have to tell it exactly where to go. So the y position is exactly where the finger is (so no need to subtract deltay). The x position, you want to keep it, so it must remain the x position of the car when you started touching

Comment: I get the idea what you talking about sir, but the problem is i dont know how to get the position of the car?

Comment: i try to put the  (transform.position.x , touchpos.y)

Comment: Thanks for your help  i already answer my problem, thanks to you :)